# ServiceStack.OrmLite: using aliases in SqlExpression for anonymous types

Tags: c#, sql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am posting this question here, as I'm still waiting for approval on the ServiceStack customer forum.
It's a rather specific question, so I don't expect many can help... **@mythz** :)

I'm migrating ServiceStack from v5.4 to v5.7 and there is an issue with aliases in `SqlExpression`.

I wrote a custom sql concat to get a "kind-of-csv-format" in one column, to merge data into one column, when using unions.
From the SQL side, simplified version would be:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Col1, ',', Col2) as Data FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(Col3, ',', Col4, ',', Col5) as Data FROM Table2
```

In C#, using OrmLite api, I do:

```
                var q1 = db.From<Table1>();
                q1.Select(x => new
                {
                    Data = Sql.Custom(q1.ConcatWithSeparator("@delimiter", y => new { y.Col1, y.Col2 }))
                });
```

`ConcatWithSeparator` is my custom method, that calls the underlying `IOrmLiteDialectProvider.SqlConcat()` under the hood, inserting before the `@delimiter` between the members of anonymous types.

That gave me:
`SELECT CONCAT("Table1"."Col1", @delimiter, "Table1"."Col2") AS DATA FROM "Table1"`

This worked well for the v5.4, but as I noticed, in v5.7, there was a change introduced in method`SqlExpression.SetAnonTypePropertyNamesForSelectExpression()`
(https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/v5.7/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Expressions/SqlExpression.cs)

```
            if (arg is ConditionalExpression ce ||                           // new { Alias = x.Value > 1 ? 1 : x.Value }
                arg is BinaryExpression      be ||                           // new { Alias = x.First + " " + x.Last }
                arg is MemberExpression      me ||                           // new { Alias = DateTime.UtcNow }
                arg is ConstantExpression ct)                                // new { Alias = 1 }
            {
                IOrmLiteConverter converter;
                var strExpr = !(expr is PartialSqlString) && (converter = DialectProvider.GetConverterBestMatch(expr.GetType())) != null
                    ? converter.ToQuotedString(expr.GetType(), expr)
                    : expr.ToString();

                return new PartialSqlString(strExpr + " AS " + member.Name);
            }
```

In particular, it's about this check:

```
            if (
                ...
                arg is MemberExpression      me ||                           // new { Alias = DateTime.UtcNow }
                ...
                )
```

This evaluates to true also for `new { x.Col1 }`, as it's a short for `new { Col1 = x.Col1 }` which further makes the sql syntax `Col1 as Col1`

In my concat, it results in a wrong SQL
`SELECT CONCAT("Table1"."Col1" AS Col1, @delimiter, "Table1"."Col2" AS Col2) AS DATA FROM "Table1"`

So the real question is, shouldn't there be an extra check, that if it's a `MemberExpression me`, also `me.Member.Name != member.Name`? Or maybe some extra configuration option to bypass the alias generation?

Or... is there any other, easier approach to achieve, what am I trying to do? (I have to support MySQL, MSSQL, Sqlite and PostgreSQL).

***Update, regarding @mythz answer below***

Unfortunately, it's still not working as expected. But I think, we are getting closer.
The converter here:

```
IOrmLiteConverter converter;
var strExpr = !(expr is PartialSqlString) && (converter = DialectProvider.GetConverterBestMatch(expr.GetType())) != null
    ? converter.ToQuotedString(expr.GetType(), expr)
    : expr.ToString();

return new PartialSqlString(strExpr != member.Name
    ? strExpr + " AS " + member.Name
    : strExpr);
```

evaluates the expression to quoted string, so in the end there is a check `"\"Col1\"" != "Col1"`.

Additionally, I also wrote a version of `ConcatWithSeparator<Table1, Table2>` that can take a lambda as `(t1, t2) => new { t1.Col1, t2.Col1 }`.
In that case, it will evaluate member expression into something like `"Table1"."Col1"` (depending on DBMS) - I hope, multi-table version is not a hit-in-the-wall and it still can be implemented without raw sql...

Comment: Approval in the [ServiceStack Customer Forums](https://forums.servicestack.net/) is automatic based on whether your Email matches a ServiceStack account with an active License Subscription. If you're using a valid email with an active subscription please email team@servicestack.net so we can manually verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed it to not use the alias when the alias is the same name in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/d9d054bc03b2136e9b75655c0933e20914dd7064).

This change is available from the latest v5.7.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: That's a fast one!
I put the update in my original question, as I couldn't fit it in the comment.

Comment: @l3m00r the check is now quotes agnostic in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/5967867a7b6b4fb8855f24faf763633e68dcfad6), you'll need to [clear your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages) to download the latest v5.7.1 packages.

Comment: Great! Works like charm for a single table. However, as I expected, when using in JOINs, the evaluated ```MemberExpression``` will get prefixed with a type/table name: ```"Table1"."Col1"```, so stripping quotes will not help in that case.

Comment: @l3m00r This should now be supported from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/ab2854b025f53511a92b781a83c801899f8684dc) which is also available from the latest v5.7.1 on MyGet

Comment: Thanks! SQL queries are running now without an issue.